# Hibernate: NonUniqueObjectException while insert

Tags: java, hibernate

Trying to insert a new Entity using hibernate and it is throwing me this exception:

```
a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session
```

I understand that this error is coming because hibernate finds a similar object in the memory. But I am creating a new object every time before inserting. Does it have anything to do with `sequence`?
**hbm**

```
<class name="MyObject" table="My_Object">
    <id column="object_id" name="id" type="long">
        <generator class="sequence">
            <param name="sequence">OBJ_SEQ</param>
        </generator>
    </id>
    <property name="column1" column="column_1" type="string" not-null="true"/>
    <property name="column2" column="column_2" type="string" not-null="true"/>
    <property name="column3" column="column_3" not-null="true" type="string"/>
</class>
```

Comment: Maybe your `MyObject` class overwrites `equals()` and `hashcode()` and this implementation does not refer to the `object_id`? In this case hibernate might find an object in the session cache that is "equal" to your new object, although it is actually a different one?

Comment: Jack may be right, but just a word of caution: if you add the id to your hashcode/equals methods, that may have its own set of dangers. The id will be null when you first instantiate an object (before it's inserted into the db and the id is generated, presumably) and then any collections (e.g. hashmaps, hashsets, etc.) in which the object exists may not "find" it after the ID has changed (post insertion) due to the hashcode being different at insertion time and lookup time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you are trying to persist an entity, a entity with the same id is already present in the database. Reason for this can be, you are manually assigning a value to the id, or you have reset the OBJ_SEQ in database.